# angularJS authentification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make an authentication form but I'm not getting my data.
I'm having problems with crud operation I'm trying to make this authentication work but I'm getting wrong data!

here is my form

```
<form role="form"  ng-submit="ajaxPost()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Login" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control input" ng-model="user.pass" placeholder="Mot de passe"/>
      </div>


      <div class="checkbox input">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.remember"> Se souvenir de moi
        </label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:50%; width:10%;" >Connexion</button>

      <div class="form-group"> 
        <label style="margin-left:49%;"><a href="">Mot de passe oublié ?</a></label>
      </div>
```

my controller.js

```
function LoginController($scope,$http) {
$scope.ajaxPost= function(){


    var postData = {};
    postData.Login = $scope.user.email;
    postData.Pass = $scope.user.pass;

    alert(postData.Login + "  " + postData.Pass);

    $http({
    url: "services/user.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: "login="+postData.Login+"&password="+postData.Pass,

}).success(function(data) {
   alert(data);
}).error(function(data) {
   alert("erreur");
});

}
}
```

is this the way to send data?

here is the console log

```
<br />
```

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\wamp\www\Anypli-Web\services\user.php on line *10*
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0005258216{main}(  )..\user.php**:**0



( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\Anypli-Web\services\user.php on line *11*
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0005258216{main}(  )..\user.php**:**0

{"items":null}

Comment: `C:\wamp\www\Anypli-Web\services\user.php` - Line 10 - what is that line?

Comment: $login = $_POST['login'];